# what is object html collection in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I try to get `var allPTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");` and there is no p tag at all in the document the variable is still not empty there is still something. If I do `if(allPTags !== "") { alert(something);}` it dose not alert; How do I compare empty value in it?

Comment: Use `length` property, `if(allPTags.length) { alert(something);}`

Comment: thanks that works well

Comment: _what is object html collection_ Why not read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var allPTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
if(allPTags.length>0){
  alert("stackoverflow"); // your message if any P tag is present.
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: documentByTagName("p") will return the array of all tags, Suppose we have 6 <p>. allPTags.length will return 6.

Answer (score 1):

Because resultant is an empty array, So you should do the following:

```js
var allPTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

if(allPTags.length) { 
  alert(something);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var allPTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var allPTagsCount = allPTags.length;
    if(allPTags !== "") { 
       alert(something);
    }
```